# Thread.join issues

Tags: c#, multithreading, join

I want to know how I would make the main thread wait before my new thread is finished it's processes before it joins back onto the main thread using `threadname'.join();`

```
BMove.Start();
```

`BMove.Join()`: <<---Here I would like the `BMove` thread to finish running its process before joining back onto the main thread that started it.

I believe my problem is that it joins my new thread back to the main thread too early.

Comment: This question is very hard to understand. Can you try to explain more clearly? Perhaps a small code sample would help.

Comment: What you have should work - the thread that you call `Join` from will wait until `BMove` terminates.  Does `BMove` start any threads of its own, or use the thread pool?

Answer (score -1):

Do you intend to block the calling (main) thread?

Edit: Modified the code. Calling join on CurrentThread (foreground) will actually not work. It could be called on the new thread created.

More details would be required in order to answer your question.

```
var newThread = ...
newThread.Join(); // Will join on calling thread and block execution until newThread is running.
```

Comment: Nothing meaningful can happen here. The concept of a thread joining itself would cause the code to block indefinitely.